# Display Bar Chart with corresponding percentage in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem that I want to create a bar chart with percentage corresponding to Y-axis values, But I don't know how it can be possible? Please suggest me for right answer.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for the `asp:chart` control can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=EE8F6F35-B087-4324-9DBA-6DD5E844FD9F&displaylang=en).